# What is the correct word order between "have/had", "been", and "already" in statements?

Tags: word-order

What is the correct word order between *have/had*, *been*, and *already* in statements like the following:

> By the time the product was officially announced, I **had already been** using it.

Or:

> By the time the product was officially announced, I **had been already** using it.

Or:

> By the time the product was officially announced, I **had been** using it **already**.

Answer (score 6):

I think the first and third would be more common, and probably the first sounds a bit more natural than the third. The middle sentence ("I had been already using it...") would be fairly rare, I think, at least among UK speakers.

Note that "By the time that..." would be a bit more natural than "When" here.

Comment: That wasn't so convincing. Please give a reference to some authoritative source to verify your opinion.

Comment: Well, it's my observation as a native speaker with a couple of linguistics degrees; you can take it or leave it...

Comment: The first and the third are indeed grammatically correct, but the second is plain wrong, not just in the UK. On the other hand, AFAIK, ["in written English, emphasis is largely a matter of controlling the way a sentence ends. The last words of English sentences carry the strongest degree of emphasis"](http://papyr.com/hypertextbooks/comp1/euphony.htm), and it is exactly the case with this example. So I would say the third is the best. What do you think?

Comment: Well, to my ear the 1st sentence is the most natural. To be honest, I see no basis for the statement that you quote.