# "There already is" or "There is already"

Tags: word-order, there-is

What is the correct word order of the verb *to be* and *already*?

> There is already a price tag.

Or:

> There already is a price tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct word order between have/had, been, and already in statements](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17019/what-is-the-correct-word-order-between-have-had-been-and-already-in-statements)

Answer (score 11):

Usually you would put the *is* first and the adverb second, unless you wanted to give special emphasis to the word *is* (as if stressing the word when speaking: "There already *is* a price tag!")

Answer (score 7):

Most speakers would shorten "There is" to "There's" so "There's already a price tag" would be the most common speaking version.

Answer (score 7):

I myself would say "There's a price tag already". (just to add further confusion)

Answer (score -1):

Before inverted, the sentence would be "A price tag is there already."
So even though being inverted, it would be "There is a price tag already.

Comment: Or it might be "A price tag is already there."

Comment: Oh that would be possible.

Comment: Thank you for the help