# Successfully submitted vs Submitted Successfully

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

When data has been submitted through a form online, which sentence below make the most sense to use? Is one grammatically correct more than the other?

> Your information has been successfully submitted.

or

> Your information has been submitted successfully.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Neither. Just say

> Your information has been submitted.

[Submitting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/submit) implies success. If the information has been submitted, then it has been successfully submitted. Otherwise, it has simply not been submitted.

> Submit, transitive verb
>
> to present or propose to another for review, consideration, or
> decision; also : to deliver formally

That said, if you really want to use one of those sentences, I would go for the second. As discussed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/102166/25030), in English the last word carries the greatest emphasis. In this case, you want to emphasize the success so I would recommend

> Your information has been submitted successfully.

Comment: I like this. If it failed, nobody says it was "submitted unsuccessfully".

Comment: I like the first suggestion. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

From a UK aspect, I'd say that either is fine.

Personally, I think I'd opt for the latter, *submitted successfully*. I can't really say why, but I think that that version puts the emphasis on the word *successfully*, which is the key word. I know it's been submitted, and I'm pleased to hear that my submission was successful. But that's a very subjective opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Both the choices,

> Your information has been successfully submitted.

and

> Your information has been submitted successfully.

are correct.

The first one is less common, but it's correct nonetheless.

I suggest "submitted successfully".

Answer (score 1):

Of the two options, I would choose "submitted successfully" because you are saying what has been done and that it was successful - this seems like a better logical layout for the information to be delivered.

I think there are minute differences in meaning between the two:

"Successfully submitted" almost implies only that the information was successfully sent (no surprises there).  By this I mean "the information submission was fine, but I don't know if it will fail in processing."

"Submitted successfully" seems to imply that the information was submitted with success, e.g. "The information was submitted and it was a success".